# How setup default value Shared Preferences in an android apk?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I make a setup class with shared preferences and in the first open apk the user use the default value and after edit if he want it with update value. My problem is when re open the apk and no create preference apk display default value else if there is old preference display this. I want update preferences onCreate with old save preferences if preferences exist(no with default value). How I create this? I want something if pref exist go to share preference...and read value...else use the default

```
String strValue ="http://www.power7.net/LEDstate.txt";//default value

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ioweb_bt);

   /* SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("dataioweb" , MODE_PRIVATE);

    String strValue = preferences.getString("Url","");
      text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUrl);
      text.setText(strValue);
    */

       edittxtUrl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
      edittxtUrl.setText(strValue);




}

public void Save(View view) {

     SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("dataioweb" , MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();  // Put the values from the UI

       edittxtUrl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
      String strUrl = edittxtUrl.getText().toString();


      editor.putString("Url", strUrl); // value to store

      // Commit to storage
      editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as for setting default value in TextView when user start your Application or any value not exist in SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
String strValue="";
TextView text;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ioweb_bt);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUrl);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("dataioweb" , MODE_PRIVATE);

    strValue = preferences.getString("Url","");
    if(!strValue.equals("")){

      text.setText(strValue);
    }
    else{
         text.setText("Set Default value here");
      }

  // your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you can get default value from preference if no value is their corresponding to your preference key

```
 SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences(preferencename, MODE_PRIVATE);
 String str=preferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
```